# How to observe DOM changes with Angular

Tags: angular, dom

I am looking to track the changes of a DOM node. I know I can see them in the inspector of the browser but with angular components often we are talking about bunch of class names so it is a time consuming to detect the delta.

[image]

I wonder if there some way to do track that programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that MutationObserver that apparently does that!

Tons of credit to https://nitayneeman.com/posts/listening-to-dom-changes-using-mutationobserver-in-angular/

I added a bit of post processing to it, et voila :

[image]